# When is it ok to call getMeasuredWidth()

Tags: android

I have a custom class that inherits `View` and has overridden `onDraw` method. Inside this method I create a `Bitmap` instance using `getMeasuredWidth()` as a parameter.

The compiler does not like it saying that it's not cool to create objects inside `onDraw` method.

So I need to move that `Bitmap` instance creation to another method. But I need to be sure that `getMeasuredWidth()` would return me up-to-date info.

My question is: what method should I use to catch changed `getMeasuredWidth()` and re-create my `Bitmap` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMeasuredWidth()` returns measured with, if you need a real width of the View in layout, use `getWidth()`.

If the Bitmap should have the width or height of the View, create it in `onSizeChanged()`

```
/**
 * This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If
 * you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old
 * values of 0.
 *
 * @param w Current width of this view.
 * @param h Current height of this view.
 * @param oldw Old width of this view.
 * @param oldh Old height of this view.
 */
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != 0 && h != 0) {
        //create Bitmap here
    }
}
```